# enigma.js chart using the latest version

Tags: qliksense

I saw this blog on enigma.js and Vega as visualization.

https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2017/03/17/creating-charts-with-enigmajs-and-vega

However, the enigma.js version used in this example is not the latest.  Would you know where to find a sample that uses the latest version? I am a bit confused on the documentation on enigma.js

Comment: Have a look at the Open Source repo, where you can find examples & the latest version of enigma.js: https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/